# Harddrive stopping for a minute from time to time

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, freeze

I have a weird problem with harddrive on Windows 8.1 machine.

Harddrive from time to time just stops all the operations - system does not freeze unless it needs to load some data from HDD for which it waits - then app freezes waiting for IO. There are no timeouts, errors and it resumes normal operaions after a minute or two. Durring event HDD indicator is lit up constantly.

What might be the problem?

MB: MSI Z87 G-45 GAMING
HDD: WD 2011.12

Comment: Backup any important data first, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SMART tool to check on the hard drive life. There are many free one's online.

They should run some tests and provide an indication of the hard drive health.

You could also run `chkdsk /f` from the command prompt

Either way, take a back up of your files and check the file integrity...